Is it legal for Sweden to disregard an EU citizen's partner's income in relation to free movement rights?
Is Swedish migration law for EU spouses legal? According to EU law for self sufficiency, as long as funds are available to the EU citizen, there is no requirement on where it must come from.
The Swedish Migration Agency however, states that income from partners residing in Sweden with the EU citizen does not count towards the right of residency. In Commission of the European Communities v Kingdom of Belgium Case no. C-408/03 European Court Reports 2006 I-02647 the court stated:

A Member State fails to fulfil its obligations under Article 18 EC and
Directive 90/364 on the right of residence if, when applying that
directive to nationals of a Member State who wish to rely on their
rights under that directive and on Article 18 EC, it excludes the
income of a partner residing in the host Member State in the absence
of an agreement concluded before a notary and containing an assistance
clause in order to assess whether the person concerned has sufficient
resources.

Based off my non-legal interpretation, the above clearly states that member states are breaching EU law by disregarding income from partners residing in the host member state.
So my question is, is the Swedish Migration Agency's position legal by denying a residency card on sufficient funds from a partner income in host member state?

Can you maybe quote or link "what swedish migration is doing"? You seem to take it as granted that everyone knows, but most of us probably don't.

I've removed your Euopean Court of Human Rights tag because this question is about EU law and the ECtHR is not an EU court.

@nvoigt Post has been updated

@Ashley you've not provided what nvoigt asked for (a quote or link to show Sweden's policy in relation to partner income for the self sufficiency test).

@JBentley Swedish Migration doesn’t have anything in writing that’s public that I can find that states that. It states on my rejection letter for a resident card that my income does not count but did not link a law or anything to it.

@Ashley If they rejected your residency because of your income, why do you think it has anything to do with your partner's income?

You have still not quoted or linked anything substantial. You got a rejection letter? Quote it. It might be closed as personalized advice, but at least it's something factual we can talk about, instead of speculating about what is in your head.

Is either of you actually Swedish maybe? EU freedom of movement does not apply if one of you is a citizen of the target nation, then it's national family reunification law that governs that. Laws are not that simple, we need context and facts. Don't make us guess and speculate, or assume things, give an answer and then you find out it's dead wrong for your specific case. That is why we are not good with personalized advice, there is too many factors in real life, people don't know about.

No, I am from the United States and my wife is Danish.

Okay, step by tiny step we are getting to an actual question. So you are from the US, your wife is from Denmark, you want to use freedom of movement to move to Sweden. Seems legit. How do you plan to support you? Your wife's job? Does she make enough to actually support the both of you? Did you submit the documents proving it? What was the actual wording of the rejection?

We submitted the savings to migration along with my income slips from my employment in Sweden. The reject letter said because my wife could not support me for 5 years with our savings, that she did not have right of residency and that my income does not count towards it because she has no residency. She got two jobs in August and makes the required amount in our rejection letter stated my swedish migration.

@Ashley It sounds like your wife doesn't have a residency permit for Sweden. If an EU citizen doesn't have residency rights in a member state, then neither does their partner. What happened when your wife applied for her residency?

@JBentley Danish citizens don’t need to apply for residency in Sweden due to the Nordic agreement. All they have to do is register with the tax agency upon arrival, which she did. They didn’t ask her for anything other than our marriage certificate. When I went to apply for my personal number, that’s when they asked for her resident rights and we supplied her savings and the tax agency granted us residency.

@Ashley Nonetheless, they seem to think that she doesn't have residency rights ("The reject letter said [...] that she did not have right of residency").

@JBentley I understand that - we obviously appealed and she got two jobs in Denmark, along with savings and a guarantor and we are still in the appeal process. My question was mainly geared towards the cited text and if that case law meant what I understood it to be, but it seems to be that I misunderstood it.

@nvoigt If the wife has a job in Sweden, her ability to support the OP is not relevant under EU law. The only requirement is that work is “real and effective” (even part-time or temporary work may be enough).

There are two things to consider in turn: your partner's right to stay in Sweden and your own. Even if your partner doesn't need a residence card or could reside on another basis like the Nordic agreement, they need to establish that they are making use of their freedom of movement rights for you to enjoy the same rights.
As an EU citizen, there are four ways for your wife to qualify for a right to reside in Sweden for more than three months: being a worker, a student, the partner of another EU citizen, or qualifying as an “economically non-active” resident. It's only in the latter case, staying under article 7(1)(b) of directive 2004/38/EC, that resources (and health insurance) come into play. I therefore assume your partner isn't working in Sweden as that's the only scenario in which the Swedish Migration Agency may ask either of you about financial resources.
Once your EU citizen spouse has established that she has “sufficient resources for themselves and their family members […]” then your right to stay in Sweden with her is straightforward:


The right of residence provided for in paragraph 1 shall extend to family members who are not nationals of a Member State, accompanying or joining the Union citizen in the host Member State, provided that such Union citizen satisfies the conditions referred to in paragraph 1(a), (b) or (c).


Note that there are no additional conditions. The Union citizen needs to satisfy the conditions in article 7(1), you (their spouse) do not. You only need to establish two facts: she is making use of her freedom of movement rights (i.e. she resides in Sweden under one of the situation discussed above) and the two of you are indeed spouses living together. Any other requirement is illegal, the only valid reason to deny you the right to live with your spouse is national security and the like.
Leaving aside students and families where all members are EU citizens, there are therefore two obvious scenarios:

Your partner works in Sweden, both of you can live in Sweden irrespective of your resources or employment situation
Your partner has sufficient resources for the two of you, both of you can live in Sweden but you need to prove that she has sufficient resources to get your residence card

The case you found is about a slightly less obvious scenario when the EU citizen would not be able to reside as a economically non-active person without the resources of the third-country (non-EU) citizen. Even in this case the court found that it would be illegal for a country to deny this family the right to reside under EU law. But you wrote in a comment that you are relying on your wife's savings so you don't even need to rely on this case, your situation ought to be a straightforward application of article 7(2) of the directive.
By contrast, if both of you want to rely on your employment income in Sweden then you would be in an analogous situation. It ought to be possible but it's a more complex argument. The most difficult thing in this case is to secure the right to work for the non-EU citizen in the first place. Once you're working and have an income then yes, it should count but it is easier to rely on the EU citizen's savings if you can.

The Swedish Migration Agency however, states that income from partners residing in Sweden with the EU citizen does not count towards the right of residency. […] So my question is, is the Swedish Migration Agency's position legal by denying a residency card on sufficient funds from a partner income in host member state?

Without having read the decision, it that's really the sole reason they invoked then yes it is clearly illegal.
Note that Sweden has long been breaking EU freedom of movement law in other respects related to their personal number so it wouldn't be surprising if they did it in this case as well. If the website found by JBentley is anything to go by, it's also possible the Agency is breaking local law in this specific decision, something that an appeal ought to resolve.
Whether all this results from improper implementation of the directive in Swedish law, some illegal policy from the Swedish Migration Agency or a mistake in this individual decision doesn't change your rights.

To add to your comment regarding why it was denied - my wife did not have enough savings for 5 years and did not include my income as they deemed she didn’t have a right of residence. Income was earned after tax agency granted me a personal number based on the savings amount we proved for my wife’s resident  rights

@Ashley The 5-year timeframe is highly questionable, I don't see why you need so much, the underlying rule is that you should prove that you have enough not to need public support and I have never heard of a country where that wasn't assessed on a yearly basis.

If you have the right to work in Sweden, already have income (or indeed will have income) and actually live together then the case you found is definitely relevant. In that context, the Migration agency's reasoning is completely backwards and just nullifies the court's decision, if someone petitions to have their spouse's income taken into account it's obviously because they don't have enough on their own, it makes no sense to only count it if they have enough financial resources.

Frame challenge: it appears that you can rely on income from other people to establish self sufficiency:

As a citizen of another EU or EEA country than Sweden you have right
of residence if you can show that you have sufficient funds, i.e.,
sufficient money to live on and support yourself in Sweden.
...
If you intend to live on another person’s assets
You need to show the following:

a letter or document confirming that the other person can support you
documents showing that this person is able to support you, such as a bank balance statement


If you think that's wrong, please provide a link to an official Swedish government page stating a policy which supports your claim.

That’s the thing - i can’t find a link from the government itself. I’ve read in a Migration Handbook found online, that income from partners do not count towards residency of EU citizens. And my reject letter from Swedish Migration Agency, states that my income doesn’t count because they side my wife didn’t have residency in Sweden.

@Ashley Your question is about the partner's income being disregarded, but you're saying your income was disregarded on your residency application. Can you clarify?

I am the partner in this situation. My wife is Danish. My income from working in Sweden after being granted a Personal Number from the Swedish Tax Agency, is not included in MY residency card application in connection to my Danish wife

@Ashley Ok, but that's a different question entirely. The question you posted is about an EU citizen (not the EU citizen's family member) meeting the self sufficiency test for becoming resident in another EU member state. Note the bolded part from the court judgment: "A Member State fails to fulfil its obligations [if], when applying that directive to nationals of a Member State who wish to rely on their rights under that directive [it] excludes the income of a partner"

@Ashley The requirements for EU citizens moving to other member states are different to the requirements for partners of EU citizens moving to other member states. What you've written in your question would only apply if your Danish wife was refused her residency because your income was disregarded on her application. I suggest you post a new question asking about income requirements for partners of EU citizens applying for their own residency.

From the way I am understand the cited quote from the case law that belgium was found in breech by not accepting income from a partner residing in member state. but maybe i’m misunderstanding.

@Ashley The case was in the context of the EU citizen applying for residency and relying on their partner's income for that application. It was not in the context of a non-EU partner of an EU citizen applying for residency and relying on their own income (see paragraph 19). These are two different scenarios.

How would that matter and what requirements do you have in mind? The reason the only scenario that made it to court is a question regarding the non-EU partner's resources is that the opposite case (EU partner with resources and non-EU partner as dependent) is completely straightforward and explicitly covered by the letter of article 7 of directive 2004/38/EC

@Relaxed It matters because I was trying to help OP understand that the premise of the question is faulty. The question purports to question why an EU citizen's partner's income is disregarded on the EU citizen's Swedish residency application, but comments have made it clear that it's actually the partner who is applying, and was refused because the EU citizen isn't a Swedish resident.

@JBentley Yes, the distinction can be important, if only to think clearly about what this case is about but I found your last comments a bit confusing. I re-read the comments and I don't see what could suggest that the EU citizen does not reside in Sweden, the OP even wrote that her wife registered with the tax agency “upon arrival”.

it's actually the partner who is applying, and was refused because the EU citizen isn't a Swedish resident That's completely normal and expected, EU citizens do not need a permit and never “apply” for residence. They might need to document that they are indeed making use of their freedom of movement rights, very often when their partners apply for their own residence card and that's when the question of resources might come up. I don't see how any of this makes the premise of the question faulty.
